# Oracle get only last 1 row data on multiple tables query

Tags: database, oracle

I have an `Oracle` query to get only last 1 row data.

```
SELECT
R.FORM_NO,
R.PART_NO,
L.L_FORM_NO,
L.HDR_ID,
L.CP_ID_SLC_FORM_NO,
S.FORM_NO,
S.PART_NO,
S.CP_ID
FROM
WA_T_QC_REVISION R,
WA_T_QC_REVISION_LIST L,
WA_T_QC_CP_SELECTED S
WHERE
R.FORM_NO = L.HDR_ID AND
S.FORM_NO = L.CP_ID_SLC_FORM_NO AND
R.PART_NO = 'PA03670-B501'
ORDER BY R.FORM_NO DESC
```

When I try to adding the query to be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT
R.FORM_NO,
R.PART_NO,
L.L_FORM_NO,
L.HDR_ID,
L.CP_ID_SLC_FORM_NO,
S.FORM_NO,
S.PART_NO,
S.CP_ID
FROM
WA_T_QC_REVISION R,
WA_T_QC_REVISION_LIST L,
WA_T_QC_CP_SELECTED S
WHERE
R.FORM_NO = L.HDR_ID AND
S.FORM_NO = L.CP_ID_SLC_FORM_NO AND
R.PART_NO = 'PA03670-B501'
ORDER BY R.FORM_NO DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
```

I got an error

```
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

What I want is to get only last 1 row data from tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate fix here is to just alias the columns having the same name such that they no longer have the same name, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        R.FORM_NO AS FORM_NO_R,
        R.PART_NO AS PART_NO_R,
        L.L_FORM_NO,
        L.HDR_ID,
        L.CP_ID_SLC_FORM_NO,
        S.FORM_NO AS FORM_NO_S,
        S.PART_NO AS PART_ON_S,
        S.CP_ID
    FROM WA_T_QC_REVISION R
    INNER JOIN WA_T_QC_REVISION_LIST L
        ON R.FORM_NO = L.HDR_ID
    INNER JOIN WA_T_QC_CP_SELECTED S
        ON S.FORM_NO = L.CP_ID_SLC_FORM_NO
    WHERE
        R.PART_NO = 'PA03670-B501'
    ORDER BY R.FORM_NO DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
```

Note also that I replaced your implicit joins with explicit inner joins.  Using formal join syntax is the preferred way of writing queries (and has been for more than 25 years).